# updating all list items

Tags: c#, monogame

Note that I'm fairly new to programming.

So I made a list for all the children sprites of the parent sprite in my game (children) and I made another list (childrenSpeed) that stores each of the millisecondsPerFrame float value from the children sprites, also attached to the parent sprite.

The problem is: if I need to update the millisecondsPerFrame value for (as an example) the playerHead, then I need to type:

```
playerHead.millisecondsPerFrame = (value);
```

but I want to make it so that I can use one line of code to update all the values in the childrenSpeed list for all the children.

I tried to use a

```
player.childrenSpeed.ForEach(...)
```

for this but I couldn't seem to let it work.

This is my LoadContent method: (the last float in the playermovement is the millisecondsPerFrame value)

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(Game.GraphicsDevice);

    // Player sprite
    player = new PlayerMovement(Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/" + s1[0]), new Vector2(150, 150), new Point(20, 35), 0, new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 11), 1.5f, 1.75f, 65f);
    playerHead = new PlayerMovement(Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/" + s1[2]), new Vector2(150, 150), new Point(20, 35), 0, new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 11), 1.5f, 1.75f, 65f);
    // playerHead is stored in the children list attached to player
    player.children.Add(playerHead);
    // the millisecondsPerFrame value from playerHead is stored in the childrenSpeed list attached to player
    player.childrenSpeed.Add(playerHead.millisecondsPerFrame);

    // Base loadcontent method
    base.LoadContent();
}
```

And this is my Update method:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{

    if (player.running == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lopen");
        player.millisecondsPerFrame = 30;
        // I need my childrenSpeed code for millisecondsPerFrame here
    }

    else if (player.running == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("gestopt");
        player.millisecondsPerFrame = 65;
        // I need my childrenSpeed code for millisecondsPerFrame here
    }

    if (player.walking == false)
    {
        // not done yet
    }

    player.Update(gameTime, Game.Window.ClientBounds);
    player.children.ForEach(c => c.Update(gameTime, Game.Window.ClientBounds));
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

So I need something like this:

```
public override void Update() 
{
    if (player.bool == ...)
    {   
        player.milliSecondsPerFrame = (value);
        // Each element in the player.childrenSpeed list = (value) (same as player)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `player.childrenSpeed = player.childrenSpeed.Select(s => value).ToList();` if you want to do in one line.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could do that! Thanks!
EDIT: but that code only works for values that are of type int. What do I need to change if I would work with a float?

Comment: (Sorry for double commenting). I tried this but it didn't work. Any other suggestions or maybe what I could have done wrong?

Comment: I understand you are new to programming, and new to SO as well. So, to make the best use of SO, always give a minimal reproducible code example so that others can work on that and give you solutions. Can you please show the specific part of your code. Show what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to SO. 

The problem I have is that I made a list named childrenSpeed that contains float values of the sprites in the children list (as seen in the first code part). 

And I want to change these values (from the childrenSpeed list) in one code line. (the values in the list will all be the same for every (children)sprite)

I will change the code parts in the question a bit so it will be easier to show what I mean.

Comment: See if the answer helps you. If it doesn't, specify your issue in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by using a foreach loop in the Update method:

```
foreach (Sprite children in player.children) // player.children is the sprite list
{
    children.millisecondsPerFrame = value; // I assign the millisecondsPerFrame float value
}
```

But thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing a simplified version of your code which you can run and test.
A pseudo `Player` class

```
class Player
{
    public float milliSecondsPerFrame { get; set; }
    public bool running { get; set; }
    public List<float> childrenSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

The Update method (note, we are actually assigning a new list)

```
public override void Update(Player player, float value)
{
    if (player.running) // == true not required
    {   
        player.milliSecondsPerFrame = value;
        player.childrenSpeed = player.childrenSpeed.Select(s => value).ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var player = new Player { running = true, milliSecondsPerFrame = 1.5F, childrenSpeed = new List<float> { 2.5F, -3.5F } };

Update(player, 1.25F); //=> milliSecondsPerFrame = 1.25F, childrenSpeed = { 1.25F, 1.25F }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this when I can!

Comment: It didn't work until I changed it to:   .ToList<int>(); -> I checked this with a console.WriteLine and the value actually changes for the list, BUT the playerHead (playerHead.milliSecondsPerFrame) value doesn't change (I can see this because the playerHead moves the same + I used a console.writeline.) Is this because the .ToList<int>(); actually makes a new list?

Comment: Why would you want `int`? In your original question, you mentioned the value is `float`! If you need `int`, you can change the type and values to int. Apart from that, the above code works just fine. And yes, as i have already noted in my answer, `ToList()` actually creates a new list.

Comment: And sorry for all the questions, but the list changes value but the float from playerHead (who was originally added in the childrenSpeed list) doesn't... So your code sample works but my original value that I wanted to change (with the list) didn't change. Only a new list was created with the new values.